# C++. If Statement won't exit

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have a function with a while loop and some if statements in it, everything runs as expected, however, when the If statement that should return the vector select_control value runs, it doesn't terminate the function after returning a value.

```
vector<int> select() {

    vector<int> select_control;
    int select;
    cin >> select;

        while (select < 10) {

            //SOME CODE THAT PUSHES VALUES INTO THE VECTOR select_control

        }

        if (select == 99){
            cout << "TERMINATING";
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(0);
        }

        else if (select == 100) {
            cout << "input complete";
            return select_control;
        }
        else {

            cout << "not a valid value";


        }





}
```

Comment: This functon has paths that return without returning value via `return` statement.

Comment: "they dont terminate the function after returning a value" - what makes you think this is the case?

Comment: It gets return earlier by exit(0) call which get encountered earlier than your return .. as `select == 99 ` happens before `select == 100`

Comment: Are your braces for while in the right spot ?  I mean only one input and cin is outside while, so why are u using while at all ? Or is there a cin inside while as well ?

Comment: It only gets one of them not both, if the value that comes from the code in the while loop is 99, everything runs fine, however if the value is 100, only the message is dislayed and the rest of functions in my main after that won't run, it just stays stuck on the message

Comment: Please post _compilable_ code that exhibits the problem - an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)

Comment: Theres a cin inside as well

Comment: @Npm1468 you need to stop commenting about what is different between the code in your question posted here and the actual code that exhibits the problem, and just _fix the code in the question_ so that we can see what code you are actually using.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `exit(0);` in your conditional statement, put a `break;`.

Comment: my bad, exit(0) works fine, its the return statement that doesn't exit the function.

Comment: @Npm1468 you don't _have_ a return statement for several control paths, including the one that was hitting `exit`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `break;` syntax. This exists out of the if stement, you don't have to include anything.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters your loop never ends because `select` never gets updated for the loop to eventually become false, you can add a `break;` after it does `return select_control` or you can just do `exit(0);` if there's absolutely nothing else the program is gonna do. You should also add `break;` or `exit(0)` after `cout << "not a valid value";` because `select` isn't being updated for the while loop to become false and exit.